# How do you display a link that when clicked opens up a new email in Outlook?

Tags: email, visual-web-part

I am creating a visual web part that displays the site owners of a SharePoint site and each site owner's email. I would like users to be able to click the email address, and this will open up a new email window in Outlook.

How can you do this in C#?

This is the code I have:

(It does not contain any code that links the email addresses to Outlook yet).

```
namespace DisplaySiteOwnersVWP.VisualWebPart1
{
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{

string mySiteURL = "my Site URL goes here";
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

public VisualWebPart1()
{
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    InitializeControl();
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dtTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
    dtTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID"));
    dtTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email"));


    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(mySiteURL))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
        {
            SPGroup ownerGroup = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
            if (ownerGroup != null)
            {
                foreach (SPUser user in ownerGroup.Users)
                {

                        DataRow dtRow = dtTable.NewRow();
                        dtRow["Name"] = user.Name;
                        dtRow["UserID"] = user.LoginName.Substring(6);
                        dtRow["Email"] = user.Email;
                        dtTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);

                }
            }

            gvOwners.DataSource = dtTable;
            gvOwners.DataBind();

        }
    }

}


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a standard web link in the format mailto:user@domain.com

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the email a link to click on. I know that the code "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:xxx@xxx.com");" will open a new email in outlook. But I do not know how to link this to the email address so that when it is clicked, the new Outlook email pops up.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813144/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-datatable-gridview

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I added a column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" " SortExpression="EmailAdress">
      <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("EmailAddress" , "mailto:{0}") %>'
                Text="Click here to email"></asp:HyperLink>

      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```